# error converting different data types (int and strings)

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a temperature converter where the user enters a temperature in Fahrenheit and it returns it in Celsius. Here's the code:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class tempconv {

    public static void main (String[]args) {
        int fahr, cel;
        String fahrstring;

        fahrstring = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(valueof("Enter your temperature in F:"));
        fahr = new int[fahrstring];
        cel = (fahr - 32) * 5/9;

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The temperature in c is " + cel);
    }

}
```

I'm trying to convert the input dialog given  into a int but the compiler stops me saying:

```
error: cannot find symbol
 fahrstring = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(>valueof("Enter your temperature in F:"));
```

so it must be a syntax error. According to the compiler I also got another error saying

```
tempconv.java:10: error: incompatible types: int[] cannot be converted to int
                  fahr = >new int[fahrstring];
```

how would the correct code be written and what exactly am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you think that `valueof("Enter your temperature in F:")` should be returning? Why do you think that `new int[fahrstring]` does?

Comment: should be a string I just realized I have no conversion the code is flawed the base of it was from my teacher

Comment: If it's from your teacher they probably wanted you to debug it. Don't use StackOverflow to do your homework for you, mate, it's in the rules ^^;

Comment: I'll remember that in the future but I've been at this for quite a while so had to ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use **double** rather than **int** as temperature may be **29.5** sometimes

```
double fahr = Double.parseDouble(fahrstring);
double c = ((fahr - 32) * (5/9));
```

Hope your problem is solved . keep coding good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to convert fahrstring to an int is by using the function:

```
Integer.parseInt(fahrstring)
```

(Here is a tutorial which demonstrates parseInt)
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/integer_parseint.htm

Comment: You might want to [double-check](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-); I think you're thinking of `valueOf`. ;)

Comment: I'm sure that valueOf ()works but so should parseInt() I edited my answer to show a tutorial for it. (I assume Tutorials point is a reputable enough site)

Comment: Sorry, that probably wasn't clear. My comment was in reference to your statement that `parseInt` returns an `Integer`.

Comment: (I'll double check the documentation)

Comment: (Fixed that on my answer)

Answer (score 0):

About the `incompatible types` error:

`int fahr` is an integer and `new int [fahrString]` will create an array object. `fahr=new int [fahrstring]` means you are trying to assign an array object to an `int` variable. This is obviously not going to work.

What can you do about it?

- Change `int fahr` to `int fahr[]` and the compatibility error wouldn't show up again.

Comment: Give me an example. It depends on your requirement.